# Best way to store user related data from db, in a webapp with OIDC authentication

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, azure-ad-graph-api, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a Core3.1 web application protected with azureAD (OpenIdConnect) and I retrieve most of the user's related data I need, from the idtoken:
Username, email, employeeId, even the user's AD groups.
I also need to get some additional data from the database and I'm not sure how I should store this data in the application, to make it available everywhere and for the entire time the user is logged in.

I don't want to use cookie. For now, I used the session.
Problem is this session expires differently from the authentication session, so I had to call a static method to check if the variables are empty and eventually doing the query again.
It works... but is ugly.

I feel like I'm supposed to handle things differently but I don't know how.

Comment: You can use .net core 3.1 in memory cache

Comment: Isn't in memory cache shared for every users?!

Comment: memory cache will be served for every user but your user_object can only be accessed by a key (like userid, token, email, username etc) for that user only

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. Do you have an example? I can't find anything related.

Comment: You can check this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

A claims based solution can work best here, where you:

1. Define a [Claims Object](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/src/logic/entities/claims/sampleClaims.ts) in your API
2. Populate it when your API first receives an access token
3. Cache the claims object for subsequent requests with the same access token
4. This cache will always be in sync with the user session

See my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) for further details on the pattern. And here is some [implementation code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/tree/master/api/src/host/oauth).

Comment: I read the article, but it doesn't seems pertinent to me.

Comment: No problem - the key points are that it is often difficult to put the claims you need in tokens, and matching up between the token and your API's own user data can be difficult. Maybe you can come up with an alternative solution that meets the same goals ..